# mounting "cgroup" to rootfs "/var/lib/docker/overlay2" at "/sys/**" "no subsystem for mount"" when deploying apache spark on minidcos

Tags: mesos, dcos

I'm trying deploy [apache spark](https://docs.mesosphere.com/services/spark/2.6.0-2.3.2/) on [minidcos](https://minidcos.readthedocs.io) using dcos catalog.

When I installed elastic, kafka and prometheus it is installed successfully as shown in the below image.

[image: services running on dcos]

But when I installed spark it failed and the error displayed in the service debug is "TASK_FAILED :  Container exited with status 125"

[image: Spark Error Failure]

The complete error trace in log is -

```
    WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap.
    container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: 

    container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"cgroup\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/319fc54c21ddaf3c611e69437342b0a40c70e76bfbd9b0c88175cb611449fa3e/merged\\\" at \\\"/sys/fs/cgroup\\\" caused \\\"no subsystem for mount\\\"\""
    docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"cgroup\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/319fc54c21ddaf3c611e69437342b0a40c70e76bfbd9b0c88175cb611449fa3e/merged\\\" at \\\"/sys/fs/cgroup\\\" caused \\\"no subsystem for mount\\\"\"".
    time="2019-02-23T01:15:36Z" level=error msg="error getting events from daemon: net/http: request canceled" 

    mounting "cgroup" to rootfs "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/merged" at "/sys/fs/cgroup" caused "no subsystem for mount""
```

Other details regarding the components installed in my system are --

```
  $sudo minidcos --version
    minidcos, version 2019.03.13.0

    $lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
    Release:    18.04
    Codename:   bionic

    $docker version
    Client:
    Version:           18.09.4
    API version:       1.39
    Go version:        go1.10.8
    Git commit:        d14af54266
    Built:             Wed Mar 27 18:35:44 2019
    OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
    Experimental:      false

    Server: Docker Engine - Community
    Engine:
    Version:          18.09.4
    API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
    Go version:       go1.10.8
    Git commit:       d14af54
    Built:            Wed Mar 27 18:01:48 2019
    OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
    Experimental:     false
```

how can I resolve this error?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue after upgrading Ubuntu from 16 to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of `minidcos` were you using?

I believe that this is an issue which was fixed in version [2019.02.16.0](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-e2e/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#id125).

Upgrade to the latest version, run `minidcos docker doctor` and then try again.

Comment: this issue still persists in latest minidcos. I tested in my local and updated the version details into question. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Now I see this issue is fixed in latest minidcos version `2019.05.03.0`

Answer (score 1):

Locate the docker container of the node it was started in:
`minidcos docker inspect`
Enter this node: `docker exec -it dcos-e2e-default-6af12-agent-1 bash` (replace the container name you found)
List all containers `docker ps -a`
Show logs of failed container `docker logs mesos-a500e80d-d694-4fb5-8baa-0b238f472f1f`